# How to sort data based on CreatedUtc Date using mongodb query in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

I want to sort the data based on CreatedUtc time. I have tried to use Reverse function, it seems to work out but still looking for some alternate option.

```
var result = _participantRepo.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Id == ParticipantId).SelectMany(x => 
    x.Relations).ToList().Where(x => x.UserId != AppUserId).Select(r => new RelationVM
                    {
                        IsOwner = r.UserId == participant.CreatedByUserId,
                        FirstName = r.FirstName,
                        LastName = r.LastName,
                        Email = r.Email,
                        UserId = r.UserId,
                        RelationType = r.RelationType,
                        Role = r.Role,
                        IsAccepted = r.IsAccepted,
                        AvatarUrl = r.AvatarUrl,
                        CreatedUtc = r.CreatedUtc
                    }).Reverse().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to concern:

- You can sort the elements of a sequence by using [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)
- You should not `.ToList()` when you have not done, So you might to read [LINQ deferred (or immediate?) execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079586/linq-deferred-or-immediate-execution) to have a better understanding.

As a result, your query should look like this

```
    var result = _participantRepo.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Id == ParticipantId).SelectMany(x => 
        x.Relations).Where(x => x.UserId != AppUserId).Select(r => new RelationVM
                        {
                            IsOwner = r.UserId == participant.CreatedByUserId,
                            FirstName = r.FirstName,
                            LastName = r.LastName,
                            Email = r.Email,
                            UserId = r.UserId,
                            RelationType = r.RelationType,
                            Role = r.Role,
                            IsAccepted = r.IsAccepted,
                            AvatarUrl = r.AvatarUrl,
                            CreatedUtc = r.CreatedUtc
                        }).Reverse().OrderBy(g => g.CreatedUtc).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `.OrderBy(g => g.CreatedUtc)` ?

Comment: [Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)