# How to write this sentinel loop having a null check in a cleaner, shorter and efficient way?

Tags: c#, loops, refactoring, sentinel, null-check

I am using `null` as a sentinel/trip value to break out of foreach:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(string sql)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(EnvironmentVariables.GetDbConnectionString());
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    var table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    return table;
}
```

```
private VacantSummaryPage SelectPropertyFromDb(string sql)
{
    VacantProperty vacantProperty = null;
    List<VacantProperty> vacantProperties = GetProperties();
    foreach (DataRow row in SqlServer.ExecuteQuery(sql).Rows)
    {
        vacantProperty = vacantProperties.Find(v => v.GetTitle().Contains(row["PartialStreetAddress"].ToString()));
        if (vacantProperty != null) break;
    }
    vacantProperty.Select();
    return new VacantSummaryPage(driver);
}
```

What it does is once a `vacantProperty` is matched where it is then no longer null, break out of the loop and `Select()` that property.

Comment: Seems like you want to `Select()` the first item, that matches a given condition. Looks like a great candidate for `First()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0

Comment: We can't answer this, too much custom code that isn't shown that we don't know about. There's not much that can be improved here in terms of performance, as Linq will also have to enumerate all items until a match is found, exactly what your code does. The obvious performance improvement is to put the "PartialStreetAddress" match directly in the SQL query, instead of pulling the table into memory and do the filtering in code.

Comment: @Olivier a loop is a loop, and a jump is a jump. Replacing a foreach with a while is not going to burn fewer CPU cycles. OP should explain what part they're trying to improve the performance of.

Comment: @CodeCaster Was just exploring other ways. I can't ask what I don't know so was hoping more experienced devs can extend a hand. Happy to know the current code does what it should, and your response was actually an objective answer. Lately, asking in SO feels like sticking your hand in the lion's cage. :)

Comment: @OlivierRogier `DataTable` does not seem to implement `IEnumerable` either: `public class DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource, ISupportInitialize, ISupportInitializeNotification, ISerializable, IXmlSerializable`. But above all else, thank you for being nice.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Haha I found it also! :) Thank you so much, it worked! I added your solution in the original post should anyone need it. If ever this thread gets reopened, post it again and I will upvote and accept. I offer you this meme as my token of thanks - https://devhumor.com/media/thank-you-guys-you-are-the-real-heroes

Comment: @silver Not so wrong, but not really true. It's quantum...

Comment: @OlivierRogier What I also learned today is LINQ comprehension query. Thanks for showing the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a "single line" instruction using a LINQ comprehension query (SQL-like syntax):

```
private VacantSummaryPage SelectPropertyFromDb(string sql)
{
  var query = from row in SqlServer.ExecuteQuery(sql).Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
              from property in GetProperties()
              where property.GetTitle().Contains(row["PartialStreetAddress"].ToString())
              select property;
  vacantProperty = query.FirstOrDefault();
  if ( vacantProperty != null )
    vacantProperty.Select();
  return new VacantSummaryPage(driver);
}
```

Using only `First` will raise an exception if not found, so with `FirstOrDefault` we can control the not found case, unless exception control is preferred.

Here the query itself is deferred, and it is evaluated when calling the First/FirstOrDefault or a ToList() for example.

[LINQ deferred (or immediate?) execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079586/linq-deferred-or-immediate-execution)

[Deferred Execution of LINQ Query](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution)

[LINQ: Why is it called "Comprehension Syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229187/linq-why-is-it-called-comprehension-syntax)

[Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

[LINQ Query Syntax (Comprehensive)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax)

[LINQ Method Syntax (Lambda)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-method-syntax)

*Good to know*

[TypedTableBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.typedtablebase-1) used by [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset) allow to directly implements `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and so also [Typed DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets).

Comment: You the real mvp! Will have a look at those docs :))

Comment: Can you explain how this is cleaner, shorter or more efficient?

Comment: @CodeCaster Compared to the original code? No loop. No if. No break (in case of using for/foreach). The loop is replaced by a single Linq query. Total: six lines instead of nine (I don't count the added null-check test, or 5 lines if putting the call to First after the select, but less readable I estimate). Easy and quick to read and understand. Do you want more reasons? More intuitive, I think. Better maintainable. In tune with the times. I prefer comprehension syntax over lambda, but lambda is cool too, and can be shorter and more powerfull, but the opposite is true, it depends on cases.